# Объектно-ориентированная бд

Tags: oracle, sql

Недавно пользовался объектно-ориентированной базой данных и мне это понравилось. Есть библиотека db4o на java и c#. Но там нужно самому создавать классы и так далее. Меня интересует есть ли такая программа которая сама конвертирует реляционную базу данных в объектно-ориентированную? Например, класс будет получать название определенной таблицы, объект класса - это строка таблицы, поля класса - это столбцы, а объект будет инкапсулироваться в объект если между ними есть связи. в итоге на выходе будет один объект в котором запихнуто все остальное. Такое вручную я могу сделать. Может у кого есть что-то автоматическое?

Comment: а вы ORM использовать не пробовали?

Comment: а можно ссылку на одну из таких систем?

Comment: почитайте про NHibernate или Entity Framework (это для C#)

Comment: теоретически такую утилиту написать можно и самому врядли на это уйдет много времени. правда не факт что получится генерировать код который 100% рабочий (т.е сгенерировать обычный бин не проблема но всякие нюансы типа импортов для аннтотаций итд итп...)